# Is VLFeat's SIFT implementation in parallel?

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing, computer-vision, multicore, sift

As we know, the downhill of SIFT compared to other detector/descriptors is speed: is usually much slower.

However, parallel implementations could solve the problem even if we want to describe one image. **Notice that I'm talking about using multiple cores, not GPU.**

VLFeat has its own [SIFT implementation](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_sift.html) (and also [Dense SIFT](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html)), and I was wondering if it's implemented in parallel or not.

*Bonus question:* if not, do you know any open source parallel implementation of SIFT?

Comment: Homework: Run it and check CPU utilization during...

Comment: Do you know any code which use one these tools from the C api? Googling didn't help so much :(

Comment: Sorry, no. just Matlab.   OpenCV has SIFT that can be called from C.  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html

Answer (score 1):

After testing it, and seeing that only one processor is used, I think SIFT implementation is serial.